# what are other conditions for winsock error WSAENOBUFS (10055) to be thrown?

Tags: c#, windows, networking, tcp, ip

Outside of port exhaustion what other causes can cause `WSAENOBUFS (10055)` to be thrown? I have an c# application and one of its native dependencies (nanomsg) throws this error when connecting to it's server component. Both the client and server are running on the same physical machine, connected through their `eth` interface, running a stock `Windows 10` with latest updates installed.

When I look up this error on the internet it's a common error. And often it's suggested it's because of port exhaustion. Microsoft even has a dedicated webpage https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/troubleshoot-tcpip-port-exhaust

I suspect in my scenario that it isn't because of port exhaustion, so I'm looking for a different explanation of what could cause this. If anybody has any idea, that can point of me in the right direction I'd very much appreciate it.

Symptoms:

- Frequently the computer comes into a bad state, where `WSAENOBUFS (10055)` is the underlying cause of an application crash. The computer has been working for about 1 year, without any problems, but of late the problem is getting more persistent.
- Client on same physical computer crashes due to `WSAENOBUFS (10055)`
- Client on a different physical computer but to the same server is not throwing `WSAENOBUFS (10055)`
- Client crashes on the `connect` call. The client is requesting the server to create a new socket and then use the temporary socket to exchange the file/data blob.
- Recreated a smaller test version of the client and server (https://gist.github.com/phr34k/6afa59221a746c9eec3ecc8cad13086a).
- When the test client connects to the real server, it crashes on `WSAENOBUFS (10055)`
- When the test client connects to the test server, it works as expected
- After a reboot of the machine, process kill of the server process the problem still persists.
- Computer works fine with other networking services like `teamviewer`, `tightvnc`, `chrome remote desktop`, `firefox`, `chrome`

---

I ran the following code to determine (from the Microsoft page):

```
Get-NetTCPConnection | Group-Object -Property State, OwningProcess | Select -Property Count, Name, @{Name="ProcessName";Expression={(Get-Process -PID ($_.Name.Split(',')[-1].Trim(' '))).Name}}, Group | Sort Count -Descending
```

My process returns the following results:

```
Count Name              ProcessName        Group
----- ----              -----------        -----
   46 Established, 4716 testapp            {MSFT_NetTCPConnection (InstanceID = "192.168.1.10??50260??165.22.50.15??...
   12 Bound, 4716       testapp            {MSFT_NetTCPConnection (InstanceID = "0.0.0.0??50260??0.0.0.0??0"), MSFT_...
   5 Listen, 4716       testapp            {MSFT_NetTCPConnection (InstanceID = "127.0.0.1??6261??0.0.0.0??0"), MSFT...
```

The rest of the processes are just stock windows processes like scvhost, the most exciting one of my own test applications which just totals to about 50 sockets. Not really enough for port exhaustion to occur. During the runtime of the process, it uses around 20MB-25MB of memory so also here it's not really leaking any memory or handles.

Edit:

```
C:\Users\server>netsh int ipv4 show dynamicport tcp

Protocol tcp Dynamic Port Range
---------------------------------
Start Port      : 49152
Number of Ports : 16384
```

There's a total of 16000 ports available, again would kinda feel rare for port exhaustion to actually occur.

Comment: From cmd.exe try >Netstat -a.    I suspect you are getting a "Time Wait" error which occurs when both the client and server tries to close a connection simultaneously and locks the connection so you can't reopen the connection.

Comment: Nope, everything returned by `netstat -a` is either in listening or established.

Comment: A similar issue does show bad Netstat (see https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/ab10790a-8dfb-4523-9342-e137e84d2544/running-out-of-tcp-ports-according-to-windows-eventlog-but-only-479-active-tcp-connections?forum=winservergen&force_isolation=true).  Try seeing if you are getting errors using following ping from cmd.exe >Ping -t -l 65500.  Using long ping message sometimes will show that error are occurring.  Also check time of ping.  the time should be under 1 millisecond.

Comment: TCP has retry tables that are kept and when errors start occurring the table sizes grow.  So while ping is running check Task Manager and see if the memory starts to grow.

Comment: Pinging returns a time < 1ms and an TTL=128 consistently. While pinging, the memory usage in the server application isn't increasing in size. Just normal fluctuation at around a steady 20mb in memory.

Comment: Did you see following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/networking/connect-tcp-greater-than-5000-error-wsaenobufs-10055?force_isolation=true Make sure you read the link in More Information.

Comment: I did. If my interpretation of that article is correct it's basically about when you do bind("*:0") windows automatically assign a free port from the system. However, I fail to what it really means.

Comment: I understand that ephemeral ports are a reserved range of short-lived tcp connections, my understanding is when you perform bind("*:0") windows will auto-assign an available port and those are called ephemeral ports if not mistaken.

But I'm not getting what the article is implying. Why, and what I should change in the registry, and for what reasons. Surely, I'm not using over 5000 ephemeral ports.

Comment: @jdweng if I checkout netstat/Get-NetTCPConnection there's maybe 60-70 connections over the whole system. None are in time waiting, 2-3 are closed waiting, and the rest is spread between listenen or established.

Comment: When you have any connection in windows (serial port, tcp) data is moved using timers and temporary buffer are used in windows.  If you have a UART, windows checks dumps the receive data into a intermediate buffer, then buffer is moved to your application buffer.  Windows is a multi user operating system and does task swapping.  So your application may not be running when the data needs to be removed from UART.  So the free port is temporary buffers.  You may not be using 5000 ports but the operating system may be using the  ports. the registry setting is MACHINE (not user).

Comment: Close Waiting means the FIN was sent to far end of connection and waiting for an ACK.  I think Time Wait means the ACK didn't occur so the Close Waiting gets moved to Time Wait.  If windows is busy doing another process the temp buffers grows since the data can't get moved to the processes that are final destinations.

Comment: @jdweng so what are you proposing that I should increase the number from 5000 to something else? How do I actually confirm the number 5000 needs any modification in the first place.

Comment: I do not know what the root cause to the issue.  I'm just giving some reasons why it is happening.   I do not know every thing you system is doing.  A slow machine or a machine that is being used by another application which uses a lot of resources can get backed up.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same condition when I manually cause my computer to hibernate by pressing the "moon" key. I am using C++, not C#, so I get a raw error code from WSASendTo. As in your case, the error is WSAENOBUFS = 10055. This is repeatable.

It makes sense that ~some~ error is returned. Network drivers on Windows are required to respond to various power-states of the computer as indicated to them by the kernel. It might be the case that WSAENOBUFS is underlying driver's way of saying, "I am going into low-power state, so there is no hope of the call that you made succeeding in any reasonable time. In fact, I have deallocated my buffers to service such a call."

Comment: The problem for me happen(s) with a running application with a continued uptime e.g. computer is shutdown at night (fast boot), service gets paused/resumed. In my situation the problem occurs because receive buffers getting full over time or due to events. After migrating from nanomsg  to an embedded http server for file transfer the problems is seldomly occuring (once every 3/4 months, instead of bi-weekly).

Comment: Just the fact that there doesn't seem to be way to get any metrics to investigate and all your other network application working is misleading.

Comment: Are you saying that the problem occurs whether you shutdown the computer? What is the sequence that cause the problem? Shutdown, bring-up, error (all the time, or only some time)?

Comment: In my case you can hold shift during shutdown to a S5 power-state the problem disipates, if you recover from other sleeping states like S4 (default from fastboot) the problem will persist across reboots.

The sequence is computer starts 7am -> background service is started/resumed -> interacts with other network devices -> 9pm computer is shutdown (S4) -> service is paused before hybernate. 

Before shutdown every night an app that connects to the service to read out some information, and after a couple of days it'd fail on that error, almost a bi-weekly occurance.